# How to handle system shutdown event using Avalonia framework on both Windows and Linux systems?

Tags: c#, linux, windows, avalonia

I'm developing an application using C# with Avalonia framework. When system shuts down I need to perform some tasks (write logs and metadata to files) for application to complete job gracefully.
Previously using WPF on Windows I used subscription to `Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionEnding` event. But as namespace says, it is OS dependent.
In Avalonia I tried to handle `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit` or `((IClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetime)ApplicationLifetime).Exit` events but neither of them fired.
So, question is, what is the correct way to handle OS shutdown on both systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try the shutdown event, it's signature is as follows...

```
((IClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetime)ApplicationLifetime).ShutdownRequested += delegate(object? sender, ShutdownRequestedEventArgs e) 
{
    //Write logs and metadata to files here...
};
```